# three.js "exploding" an object in predefined pieces

Tags: javascript, three.js, position

This is a sort of a follow up question of my last problem. I want to explode (technical drawing style) an imported .obj geometry which contains n .obj parts.

For example a table as object, each part is one .obj, four legs and a table top. 
5 files. loading them is no problem. Now each objects position is 0,0,0 that means I need to get the world position of them, which I did with this function:

```
    function absPos( myMesh ) {    
      myMesh.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
      var boundingBox = myMesh.geometry.boundingBox;   
      var position = new THREE.Vector3();
      position.subVectors( boundingBox.max, boundingBox.min );
      position.multiplyScalar( 0.5 );
      position.add( boundingBox.min );    
      position.applyMatrix4( myMesh.matrixWorld );    
      var abspos = {x:position.x,y:position.y,z:position.z};
      return abspos;      
    }
```

now I did assume that setting the object´s position to their world positions would just happen to move them to another world position but keep their relation but that is not the case. So I cannot just use the objects world position and use it to translate the objects until I mess with the world position?

As the objects position is 0,0,0 they don´t have a relation to each other and I cannot just multiply the values to "explode" the geometry.

Is there any chance to achieve this without messing with the world positions?

Comment: If you won't use `absPos(...)`, how parts of a so-called table will be positioned in the scene?

Comment: That code is just to show wat I use to get the absolute position. At the start the position of the Table elements are defined in the .obj files so I don´t translate anything. However as you probably know obj.position.x/y/z just returns 0,0,0.It doesn´t give me any information in what direction the legs/table top should "explode" but it does give me the option to place the table elements somewhere. Now I could use the world positions I get with absPos to find out if the positions are negative or positive and could just add a positive or negative value to object.position to replace the elements.

Comment: Okay that works even as multiplicator. It isn´t as perfect as I´d like to have but I guess I can cheat with some corrections.